# TAB separated txt file from Excel VBA/MACRO

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make an excel file that has a some values in it..into a tab separated values text file....
solution 1
-i can save it as a tab separated text file..but the issue is it also saves the column headers which i dont need.Dont know how to change that !

solution 2--i have this code:

```
Public Sub CharacterSV()
    Const DELIMITER As String = " |"
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "Test.txt" For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("A2:A" & _
                Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        With myRecord
            For Each myField In Range(.Cells, _
                    Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

Now i can control which cells to tab separate with the  "Range" function in my code..however..how do i  **specify the tab delimiter** "Const DELIMITER " instead of the pipe separator? Also..it seems to add the delimeter before the first value (ie from the first cell) how do i make it to start from the after the first value (but include the first cell value in the txt file?)

Answer (score 4):

`how do i specify the tab delimiter "Const DELIMITER " instead of the pipe separator?`

for the above, you can use `vbTab`

Comment: THANKS...!! WORKS..how do i add a message completed?

Comment: @andreas If you are asking how do you mark this as the accepted answer, there is a check mark to the left of it underneath the up and down vote arrows.

Answer (score 2):

> Also..it seems to add the delimeter
>   before the first value (ie from the
>   first cell) how do i make it to start
>   from the after the first value (but
>   include the first cell value in the
>   txt file?)

This line of code:

```
sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myfield.txt
```

adds the delimiter first, because the first time through your loop, sOut = "".  Change this code to:

```
sOut = sOut & myfield.txt & DELIMITER
```

Then after your loop has finished, if you don't want the extra delimiter on the end, use a trim operation to remove it.